# Is acquiesce used correctly in the following exchange?

Tags: grammaticality, verb-agreement

> Joy wants some candy.
>   That can be acquiesced.

I have two main questions here:

1) Am I correct in thinking that "That" represents a noun such as "the request", making the second sentence equivalent to "Joy's request can be acquiesced"?

2) Assuming the answer to 1) is yes, and the sentence is essentially "Joy's request can be acquiesced", is the sentence correct? I wouldn't think so, as the person is the one acquiescing, not the request.

Comment: As any dictionary will tell you, *acquiesce* is an intransitive verb: one acquiesces *to* or *in* something. It cannot be cast in the passive.

Comment: Perhaps you meant "that can be arranged".

Comment: Or "That can be accommodated".

Comment: Those are what I would have used. My friend is the one who used acquiesce and we disagreed on if it was correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subject of the intransitive verb "[acquiesce](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acquiesce)" is always a person, rather than a request; the "object" is indicated in a prepositional phrase, using the prepositions "to" or "in" (e.g., "He acquiesced to her demands"). It is synonymous with "relent" or "submit". The word "acquiesce" comes from the Latin verb "acqiuescere", meaning "to put into silence" (basically, to be compelled to shut up), and has always applied to the *person* making the request, not the request itself. However, your misunderstanding is a common one, as this detail is not always made explicit in the dictionary definition. The words "made to conform", "nullified", or "revised" might be an adequate replacement for "acquiesced" in your example sentence above (e.g., "That can be revised").